# Drawing a person in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to write and draw something like the below picture in LaTeX. I know how to write an ordinary text with formulas in LaTeX, but not that much professional to have something like this. Please give some hints or references to how to do that.

[image]

Comment: What about the fontawesome5 icon \faMale?

Comment: You could just use includegraphics, and get a picture from the internet, say of Da Vinci's Vitruvian Man (public domain!).

Comment: I was a bit confused about the title, until I realised I was on texSE.

Answer (score 51):

OK, I had some time to play around with Bezier curves, so I had to share it here:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    
    
        \tikzset{
        pics/man/.style={code=
        {
        \draw[#1]   
                (0,0) .. controls ++(0,-0.8) and ++(0.2,0.6) ..
                (-0.4,-1.8) .. controls ++(0.2,-0.8) and ++(0.1,0.6) ..
                (-0.5,-4.4) .. controls ++(-0.6,-0.2) and ++(0.7,0.1) ..
                (-2,-4.8) .. controls ++(0,0.3) and ++(-0.5,-0.2)  ..
                (-1,-3.8) .. controls ++(-0.1,0.9) and ++(-0.1,-0.8)  ..
                (-1,-1.8) .. controls ++(-0.3,1) and ++(-0.2,-0.8)  ..              
                (-0.9,0.9) .. controls ++(-0.1,1) and ++(0,-0.8)  ..
                (-1.2,2.8) .. controls ++(-0.4,-1) and ++(0.4,0.5)  ..
                (-2.6,0.8) .. controls ++(0.5,-0.8) and ++(0.2,-0.1)  ..
                (-3.2,-0.1) .. controls ++(-0.2,0) and ++(-0.3,-0.5)  ..
                (-3.3,0.8) .. controls ++(0.4,0.5) and ++(-0.5,-0.5)  ..        
                (-1.8,3.4) .. controls ++(0.5,0.5) and ++(-0.3,-0.1)  ..                
                (-0.7,3.9) .. controls ++(0.3,0.1) and ++(0,-0.2)  ..
                (-0.4,4.3) .. controls ++(-1.2,0.3) and ++(-1.2,0)  ..
                %
                (0,6.2) coordinate (-head) .. controls ++(1.2,0) and ++(1.2,0.3) .. % Top of the head
                %
                (0.4,4.3) .. controls ++(0,-0.2) and ++(-0.3,0.1) ..
                (0.7,3.9) .. controls ++(0.3,-0.1) and ++(-0.5,0.5) ..
                (1.8,3.4) .. controls ++(0.5,-0.5) and ++(-0.4,0.5) ..
                (3.3,0.8) .. controls ++(0.3,-0.5) and ++(0.2,0) ..
                (3.2,-0.1) .. controls ++(-0.2,-0.1) and ++(-0.5,-0.8) ..
                (2.6,0.8) .. controls ++(-0.4,0.5) and ++(0.4,-1) ..
                (1.2,2.8) .. controls ++(0,-0.8) and ++(0.1,1) ..
                (0.9,0.9) .. controls ++(0.2,-0.8) and ++(0.3,1) ..
                (1,-1.8) .. controls ++(0.1,-0.8) and ++(0.1,0.9) ..
                (1,-3.8) .. controls ++(0.5,-0.2) and ++(0,0.3) ..
                (2,-4.8) .. controls ++(-0.7,0.1) and ++(0.6,-0.2) ..
                (0.5,-4.4) .. controls ++(-0.1,0.6) and ++(-0.2,-0.8) ..
                (0.4,-1.8) .. controls ++(-0.2,0.6) and ++(0,-0.8) ..
                (0,0) ++ (0,2) coordinate (-heart) -- cycle
                ;
        },
    }}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (-1.5,0) pic(M){man={scale=0.2,pink!50!black,fill=pink}};
            \node at (M-heart) {T};
    
            \node[above = 1pt of M-head] (T) {Transplant};
            
            \draw (0,0) node [below right] {$t \longrightarrow$} -- (4,0);
        \node at (2,0.4) {$HT(t): 0000....0\;111111111$};
        \draw (2.5,0.15) --++ (0,-0.3) node[below] {$t_0$};
       
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 very nice job :-)

Comment: Is he really in latex? With the pink color, he looks nude!

Comment: @hpekristiansen not for me. Anyway, you can replace where it says 'pink'  by 'blue' . I'm

Comment: @hpekristiansen Hi. I read many times your spectacular comment ....and I often I have a smile :-) I think that it is one of many beautiful comments.

Answer (score 27):

There exist specific packages for the outlines of beings. (You probably need a very recent TeX installation.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=A]
  \koala[contour=black]
 \end{scope}
 \node[above=1ex of A](T){Transplant};
 \node[base right=2em of T,inner xsep=0pt](H){$HT(t):0000\ldots0$};
 \node[base right=0.2ex of H,inner xsep=0pt](1){$11111111$};
 \coordinate[below=0.5ex of H.south west] (P);
 \draw (P) -- (P-|1.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer the question in the title, we need a man. While I do not know the gender of the above fellow, here is a man, a snowman.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=A]
  \snowman[contour=black]
 \end{scope}
 \node[above=1ex of A](T){Transplant};
 \node[base right=2em of T,inner xsep=0pt](H){$HT(t):0000\ldots0$};
 \node[base right=0.2ex of H,inner xsep=0pt](1){$11111111$};
 \coordinate[below=0.5ex of H.south west] (P);
 \draw (P) -- (P-|1.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

I add a long code done with an external tool converting the image of the man in a file `.svg` and export it in file `.tex` code. The tool is:

https://products.aspose.app/pdf/it/conversion/svg-to-tex

The code is obviously long but it could be called the *Vitruvian man* :-) with a command of the kind:

```
\input{filename.tex}
```

The output is given:

### [image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0in,paperwidth=86pt,paperheight=127pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\filldraw[black][nonzero rule]
(35.5pt, -3.500015pt) .. controls (39pt, -6.900017pt) and (38.8pt, -11.40002pt) .. (35pt, -15.00002pt)
 -- (35pt, -15.00002pt)
 -- (35pt, -15.00002pt)
 -- (35pt, -15.00002pt) .. controls (30.2pt, -19.50002pt) and (31.7pt, -24.00002pt) .. (38.2pt, -24.00002pt)
 -- (38.2pt, -24.00002pt)
 -- (38.2pt, -24.00002pt)
 -- (38.2pt, -24.00002pt) .. controls (43.5pt, -24.00002pt) and (46.5pt, -27.40002pt) .. (54.39999pt, -42.00002pt)
 -- (54.39999pt, -42.00002pt)
 -- (54.39999pt, -42.00002pt)
 -- (54.39999pt, -42.00002pt) .. controls (61.8pt, -55.50001pt) and (62.8pt, -59.00001pt) .. (59.7pt, -59.00001pt)
 -- (59.7pt, -59.00001pt)
 -- (59.7pt, -59.00001pt)
 -- (59.7pt, -59.00001pt) .. controls (57.39999pt, -59.00001pt) and (55.7pt, -56.20001pt) .. (56.39999pt, -53.60001pt)
 -- (56.39999pt, -53.60001pt)
 -- (56.39999pt, -53.60001pt)
 -- (56.39999pt, -53.60001pt) .. controls (56.8pt, -51.90001pt) and (56.3pt, -50.30001pt) .. (54.6pt, -48.30001pt)
 -- (54.6pt, -48.30001pt)
 -- (54.6pt, -48.30001pt)
 -- (54.6pt, -48.30001pt) .. controls (53.3pt, -46.80001pt) and (49.99999pt, -42.00002pt) .. (47.3pt, -37.80001pt)
 -- (47.3pt, -37.80001pt)
 -- (42.4pt, -30.00002pt)
 -- (42.4pt, -30.00002pt)
 -- (41.1pt, -37.90001pt)
 -- (41.1pt, -37.90001pt)
 -- (41.1pt, -37.90001pt)
 -- (41.1pt, -37.90001pt) .. controls (40.4pt, -42.20001pt) and (39.9pt, -50.60001pt) .. (40pt, -56.60001pt)
 -- (40pt, -56.60001pt)
 -- (40pt, -56.60001pt)
 -- (40pt, -56.60001pt) .. controls (40.2pt, -62.60001pt) and (39.9pt, -74.40001pt) .. (39.5pt, -82.70001pt)
 -- (39.5pt, -82.70001pt)
 -- (38.7pt, -98.00001pt)
 -- (38.7pt, -98.00001pt)
 -- (43.09999pt, -101.9pt)
 -- (43.09999pt, -101.9pt)
 -- (47.5pt, -105.9pt)
 -- (47.5pt, -105.9pt)
 -- (41.8pt, -103.8pt)
 -- (41.8pt, -103.8pt)
 -- (41.8pt, -103.8pt)
 -- (41.8pt, -103.8pt) .. controls (38.7pt, -102.7pt) and (35.8pt, -101pt) .. (35.4pt, -100.1pt)
 -- (35.4pt, -100.1pt)
 -- (35.4pt, -100.1pt)
 -- (35.4pt, -100.1pt) .. controls (35pt, -99.20001pt) and (34.6pt, -93.10001pt) .. (34.5pt, -86.50001pt)
 -- (34.5pt, -86.50001pt)
 -- (34.5pt, -86.50001pt)
 -- (34.5pt, -86.50001pt) .. controls (34.4pt, -79.90001pt) and (33.8pt, -72.50002pt) .. (33.2pt, -70.00002pt)
 -- (33.2pt, -70.00002pt)
 -- (33.2pt, -70.00002pt)
 -- (33.2pt, -70.00002pt) .. controls (32.6pt, -67.50002pt) and (31.9pt, -64.30001pt) .. (31.5pt, -62.70001pt)
 -- (31.5pt, -62.70001pt)
 -- (31.5pt, -62.70001pt)
 -- (31.5pt, -62.70001pt) .. controls (31.2pt, -61.20001pt) and (30.6pt, -60.00001pt) .. (30.2pt, -60.00001pt)
 -- (30.2pt, -60.00001pt)
 -- (30.2pt, -60.00001pt)
 -- (30.2pt, -60.00001pt) .. controls (28.9pt, -60.00001pt) and (26pt, -79.10001pt) .. (25.7pt, -89.70001pt)
 -- (25.7pt, -89.70001pt)
 -- (25.7pt, -89.70001pt)
 -- (25.7pt, -89.70001pt) .. controls (25.6pt, -95.40001pt) and (25pt, -100.4pt) .. (24.5pt, -100.9pt)
 -- (24.5pt, -100.9pt)
 -- (24.5pt, -100.9pt)
 -- (24.5pt, -100.9pt) .. controls (23.9pt, -101.4pt) and (21pt, -102.8pt) .. (18pt, -103.9pt)
 -- (18pt, -103.9pt)
 -- (12.5pt, -106pt)
 -- (12.5pt, -106pt)
 -- (15.2pt, -103.6pt)
 -- (15.2pt, -103.6pt)
 -- (15.2pt, -103.6pt)
 -- (15.2pt, -103.6pt) .. controls (16.7pt, -102.3pt) and (18.9pt, -100.5pt) .. (20pt, -99.70001pt)
 -- (20pt, -99.70001pt)
 -- (20pt, -99.70001pt)
 -- (20pt, -99.70001pt) .. controls (22.2pt, -98.20001pt) and (22.2pt, -98.00001pt) .. (21.1pt, -81.80001pt)
 -- (21.1pt, -81.80001pt)
 -- (21.1pt, -81.80001pt)
 -- (21.1pt, -81.80001pt) .. controls (20.5pt, -72.90001pt) and (20pt, -59.90001pt) .. (20.1pt, -53.00001pt)
 -- (20.1pt, -53.00001pt)
 -- (20.1pt, -53.00001pt)
 -- (20.1pt, -53.00001pt) .. controls (20.2pt, -45.10001pt) and (19.7pt, -38.70001pt) .. (18.8pt, -35.70001pt)
 -- (18.8pt, -35.70001pt)
 -- (17.5pt, -30.90001pt)
 -- (17.5pt, -30.90001pt)
 -- (11pt, -40.70001pt)
 -- (11pt, -40.70001pt)
 -- (11pt, -40.70001pt)
 -- (11pt, -40.70001pt) .. controls (6.499998pt, -47.50002pt) and (4.499998pt, -51.50002pt) .. (4.4pt, -53.80001pt)
 -- (4.4pt, -53.80001pt)
 -- (4.4pt, -53.80001pt)
 -- (4.4pt, -53.80001pt) .. controls (4.299999pt, -57.10001pt) and (2.799999pt, -59.00001pt) .. (0.299999pt, -59.00001pt)
 -- (0.299999pt, -59.00001pt)
 -- (0.299999pt, -59.00001pt)
 -- (0.299999pt, -59.00001pt) .. controls (-2.1pt, -59.00001pt) and (-1.000001pt, -54.30001pt) .. (2.9pt, -47.40001pt)
 -- (2.9pt, -47.40001pt)
 -- (2.9pt, -47.40001pt)
 -- (2.9pt, -47.40001pt) .. controls (4.999998pt, -43.60001pt) and (8.399998pt, -37.50002pt) .. (10.4pt, -33.80001pt)
 -- (10.4pt, -33.80001pt)
 -- (10.4pt, -33.80001pt)
 -- (10.4pt, -33.80001pt) .. controls (14.2pt, -26.80001pt) and (17.6pt, -24.00002pt) .. (22.3pt, -24.00002pt)
 -- (22.3pt, -24.00002pt)
 -- (22.3pt, -24.00002pt)
 -- (22.3pt, -24.00002pt) .. controls (23.7pt, -24.00002pt) and (25.8pt, -23.20001pt) .. (27pt, -22.20001pt)
 -- (27pt, -22.20001pt)
 -- (27pt, -22.20001pt)
 -- (27pt, -22.20001pt) .. controls (28.9pt, -20.60001pt) and (29.1pt, -20.00002pt) .. (28.1pt, -18.20001pt)
 -- (28.1pt, -18.20001pt)
 -- (28.1pt, -18.20001pt)
 -- (28.1pt, -18.20001pt) .. controls (27.5pt, -17.00002pt) and (26.5pt, -16.00002pt) .. (25.9pt, -16.00002pt)
 -- (25.9pt, -16.00002pt)
 -- (25.9pt, -16.00002pt)
 -- (25.9pt, -16.00002pt) .. controls (25.4pt, -16.00002pt) and (24.2pt, -14.40002pt) .. (23.5pt, -12.50002pt)
 -- (23.5pt, -12.50002pt)
 -- (23.5pt, -12.50002pt)
 -- (23.5pt, -12.50002pt) .. controls (19.9pt, -4.000015pt) and (29.1pt, 2.999985pt) .. (35.5pt, -3.500015pt) -- cycle
(26.5pt, 1.099983pt) .. controls (21pt, -1.300018pt) and (18.6pt, -8.400017pt) .. (21.4pt, -13.90002pt)
 -- (21.4pt, -13.90002pt)
 -- (21.4pt, -13.90002pt)
 -- (21.4pt, -13.90002pt) .. controls (22.4pt, -15.70001pt) and (23.8pt, -17.40002pt) .. (24.6pt, -17.70001pt)
 -- (24.6pt, -17.70001pt)
 -- (24.6pt, -17.70001pt)
 -- (24.6pt, -17.70001pt) .. controls (27.4pt, -18.70001pt) and (26pt, -20.80001pt) .. (22pt, -21.50002pt)
 -- (22pt, -21.50002pt)
 -- (22pt, -21.50002pt)
 -- (22pt, -21.50002pt) .. controls (15pt, -22.70001pt) and (12.2pt, -25.50002pt) .. (4.4pt, -39.70001pt)
 -- (4.4pt, -39.70001pt)
 -- (4.4pt, -39.70001pt)
 -- (4.4pt, -39.70001pt) .. controls (0.299999pt, -47.00002pt) and (-3.200001pt, -54.10001pt) .. (-3.6pt, -55.50001pt)
 -- (-3.6pt, -55.50001pt)
 -- (-3.6pt, -55.50001pt)
 -- (-3.6pt, -55.50001pt) .. controls (-4.400001pt, -58.80001pt) and (-2.500001pt, -61.00001pt) .. (1.099998pt, -61.00001pt)
 -- (1.099998pt, -61.00001pt)
 -- (1.099998pt, -61.00001pt)
 -- (1.099998pt, -61.00001pt) .. controls (4.499998pt, -61.00001pt) and (7.499998pt, -57.20001pt) .. (6.499998pt, -54.10001pt)
 -- (6.499998pt, -54.10001pt)
 -- (6.499998pt, -54.10001pt)
 -- (6.499998pt, -54.10001pt) .. controls (6.099998pt, -52.70001pt) and (6.999998pt, -50.50002pt) .. (9.799999pt, -46.80001pt)
 -- (9.799999pt, -46.80001pt)
 -- (9.799999pt, -46.80001pt)
 -- (9.799999pt, -46.80001pt) .. controls (11.9pt, -43.90001pt) and (14.3pt, -40.40001pt) .. (15pt, -39.00002pt)
 -- (15pt, -39.00002pt)
 -- (16.3pt, -36.60001pt)
 -- (16.3pt, -36.60001pt)
 -- (17.2pt, -39.00002pt)
 -- (17.2pt, -39.00002pt)
 -- (17.2pt, -39.00002pt)
 -- (17.2pt, -39.00002pt) .. controls (17.7pt, -40.40001pt) and (18.1pt, -47.10001pt) .. (18pt, -54.00001pt)
 -- (18pt, -54.00001pt)
 -- (18pt, -54.00001pt)
 -- (18pt, -54.00001pt) .. controls (17.9pt, -60.90001pt) and (18.1pt, -73.30001pt) .. (18.5pt, -81.70001pt)
 -- (18.5pt, -81.70001pt)
 -- (19.3pt, -96.90001pt)
 -- (19.3pt, -96.90001pt)
 -- (14.4pt, -101.4pt)
 -- (14.4pt, -101.4pt)
 -- (14.4pt, -101.4pt)
 -- (14.4pt, -101.4pt) .. controls (10.5pt, -104.9pt) and (9.799999pt, -106.1pt) .. (10.7pt, -107.1pt)
 -- (10.7pt, -107.1pt)
 -- (10.7pt, -107.1pt)
 -- (10.7pt, -107.1pt) .. controls (11.7pt, -108.1pt) and (13.1pt, -108pt) .. (18pt, -106.5pt)
 -- (18pt, -106.5pt)
 -- (18pt, -106.5pt)
 -- (18pt, -106.5pt) .. controls (21.3pt, -105.5pt) and (24.7pt, -103.9pt) .. (25.5pt, -103pt)
 -- (25.5pt, -103pt)
 -- (25.5pt, -103pt)
 -- (25.5pt, -103pt) .. controls (27.5pt, -100.8pt) and (29.3pt, -88.80001pt) .. (28.4pt, -83.70001pt)
 -- (28.4pt, -83.70001pt)
 -- (28.4pt, -83.70001pt)
 -- (28.4pt, -83.70001pt) .. controls (28.1pt, -81.60001pt) and (28.4pt, -77.60001pt) .. (29.1pt, -74.70001pt)
 -- (29.1pt, -74.70001pt)
 -- (29.1pt, -74.70001pt)
 -- (29.1pt, -74.70001pt) .. controls (30.2pt, -70.10001pt) and (30.5pt, -69.80001pt) .. (31.1pt, -72.00002pt)
 -- (31.1pt, -72.00002pt)
 -- (31.1pt, -72.00002pt)
 -- (31.1pt, -72.00002pt) .. controls (31.5pt, -73.40001pt) and (31.8pt, -79.60001pt) .. (31.9pt, -85.80001pt)
 -- (31.9pt, -85.80001pt)
 -- (31.9pt, -85.80001pt)
 -- (31.9pt, -85.80001pt) .. controls (32pt, -100.7pt) and (33pt, -103pt) .. (40.5pt, -105.8pt)
 -- (40.5pt, -105.8pt)
 -- (40.5pt, -105.8pt)
 -- (40.5pt, -105.8pt) .. controls (47.3pt, -108.4pt) and (49.99999pt, -108.6pt) .. (49.99999pt, -106.4pt)
 -- (49.99999pt, -106.4pt)
 -- (49.99999pt, -106.4pt)
 -- (49.99999pt, -106.4pt) .. controls (49.99999pt, -104.7pt) and (43.3pt, -98.00001pt) .. (41.7pt, -98.00001pt)
 -- (41.7pt, -98.00001pt)
 -- (41.7pt, -98.00001pt)
 -- (41.7pt, -98.00001pt) .. controls (41.1pt, -98.00001pt) and (41pt, -92.80001pt) .. (41.5pt, -84.30001pt)
 -- (41.5pt, -84.30001pt)
 -- (41.5pt, -84.30001pt)
 -- (41.5pt, -84.30001pt) .. controls (42pt, -76.70001pt) and (42.3pt, -64.40001pt) .. (42.2pt, -57.00001pt)
 -- (42.2pt, -57.00001pt)
 -- (42.2pt, -57.00001pt)
 -- (42.2pt, -57.00001pt) .. controls (42.1pt, -49.60001pt) and (42.4pt, -42.00002pt) .. (42.8pt, -40.20001pt)
 -- (42.8pt, -40.20001pt)
 -- (43.5pt, -36.80001pt)
 -- (43.5pt, -36.80001pt)
 -- (48.7pt, -44.30001pt)
 -- (48.7pt, -44.30001pt)
 -- (48.7pt, -44.30001pt)
 -- (48.7pt, -44.30001pt) .. controls (52.39999pt, -49.60001pt) and (53.89999pt, -52.60001pt) .. (53.8pt, -54.80001pt)
 -- (53.8pt, -54.80001pt)
 -- (53.8pt, -54.80001pt)
 -- (53.8pt, -54.80001pt) .. controls (53.7pt, -58.80001pt) and (55.49999pt, -61.00001pt) .. (58.89999pt, -61.00001pt)
 -- (58.89999pt, -61.00001pt)
 -- (58.89999pt, -61.00001pt)
 -- (58.89999pt, -61.00001pt) .. controls (62.1pt, -61.00001pt) and (63.99999pt, -59.40001pt) .. (63.99999pt, -56.70001pt)
 -- (63.99999pt, -56.70001pt)
 -- (63.99999pt, -56.70001pt)
 -- (63.99999pt, -56.70001pt) .. controls (63.99999pt, -53.60001pt) and (50.2pt, -28.70001pt) .. (46.59999pt, -25.30001pt)
 -- (46.59999pt, -25.30001pt)
 -- (46.59999pt, -25.30001pt)
 -- (46.59999pt, -25.30001pt) .. controls (44.2pt, -23.10001pt) and (41.8pt, -21.90002pt) .. (38.6pt, -21.50002pt)
 -- (38.6pt, -21.50002pt)
 -- (38.6pt, -21.50002pt)
 -- (38.6pt, -21.50002pt) .. controls (36.1pt, -21.10001pt) and (34pt, -20.50002pt) .. (34pt, -20.30001pt)
 -- (34pt, -20.30001pt)
 -- (34pt, -20.30001pt)
 -- (34pt, -20.30001pt) .. controls (34pt, -20.00002pt) and (35.4pt, -18.20001pt) .. (37pt, -16.30001pt)
 -- (37pt, -16.30001pt)
 -- (37pt, -16.30001pt)
 -- (37pt, -16.30001pt) .. controls (39.3pt, -13.80001pt) and (40pt, -11.90002pt) .. (40pt, -9.000015pt)
 -- (40pt, -9.000015pt)
 -- (40pt, -9.000015pt)
 -- (40pt, -9.000015pt) .. controls (40pt, -2.000015pt) and (32.4pt, 3.599983pt) .. (26.5pt, 1.099983pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[black][nonzero rule]
(23pt, -37.20001pt) .. controls (23.1pt, -39.30001pt) and (23.2pt, -39.30001pt) .. (24.1pt, -37.70001pt)
 -- (24.1pt, -37.70001pt)
 -- (24.1pt, -37.70001pt)
 -- (24.1pt, -37.70001pt) .. controls (24.6pt, -36.80001pt) and (26pt, -36.00002pt) .. (27pt, -36.00002pt)
 -- (27pt, -36.00002pt)
 -- (27pt, -36.00002pt)
 -- (27pt, -36.00002pt) .. controls (28.8pt, -36.00002pt) and (29pt, -36.70001pt) .. (29pt, -43.90001pt)
 -- (29pt, -43.90001pt)
 -- (29pt, -43.90001pt)
 -- (29pt, -43.90001pt) .. controls (29pt, -50.60001pt) and (28.7pt, -51.90001pt) .. (27.3pt, -52.30001pt)
 -- (27.3pt, -52.30001pt)
 -- (27.3pt, -52.30001pt)
 -- (27.3pt, -52.30001pt) .. controls (26.3pt, -52.60001pt) and (27.8pt, -52.80001pt) .. (30.5pt, -52.80001pt)
 -- (30.5pt, -52.80001pt)
 -- (30.5pt, -52.80001pt)
 -- (30.5pt, -52.80001pt) .. controls (33.3pt, -52.80001pt) and (34.7pt, -52.60001pt) .. (33.8pt, -52.30001pt)
 -- (33.8pt, -52.30001pt)
 -- (33.8pt, -52.30001pt)
 -- (33.8pt, -52.30001pt) .. controls (32.3pt, -51.90001pt) and (32pt, -50.60001pt) .. (32pt, -43.90001pt)
 -- (32pt, -43.90001pt)
 -- (32pt, -43.90001pt)
 -- (32pt, -43.90001pt) .. controls (32pt, -36.70001pt) and (32.2pt, -36.00002pt) .. (34pt, -36.00002pt)
 -- (34pt, -36.00002pt)
 -- (34pt, -36.00002pt)
 -- (34pt, -36.00002pt) .. controls (35pt, -36.00002pt) and (36.4pt, -36.80001pt) .. (36.9pt, -37.70001pt)
 -- (36.9pt, -37.70001pt)
 -- (36.9pt, -37.70001pt)
 -- (36.9pt, -37.70001pt) .. controls (37.8pt, -39.30001pt) and (37.9pt, -39.30001pt) .. (38pt, -37.20001pt)
 -- (38pt, -37.20001pt)
 -- (38pt, -37.20001pt)
 -- (38pt, -37.20001pt) .. controls (38pt, -35.10001pt) and (37.6pt, -35.00002pt) .. (30.5pt, -35.00002pt)
 -- (30.5pt, -35.00002pt)
 -- (30.5pt, -35.00002pt)
 -- (30.5pt, -35.00002pt) .. controls (23.4pt, -35.00002pt) and (23pt, -35.10001pt) .. (23pt, -37.20001pt) -- cycle
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems very nice. There seems to be a lot of rounding errors in the output, though.

Comment: @VincentFourmond Thank you for your comment. What are your mistakes? I have used recent updating of MikTeX and it compiles correctly.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not clear. I haven't tried to compile the example, but I trust it works well. What I'm commenting on are examples like `-59.00001pt` which feels like it should be `-59pt`.
Therefore my suggestion that the algorithm used to produce the tikz output has rounding errors.

Comment: When you know I had to do mine all by hand, using curves in Word and reading control points one by one... Anyway, your man is in a very nice shape too ;)

Comment: @SebGlav Thank you for your advice and comment on my not good man...my man peraphs he is not nude..but peraphs it is a ghost :-) ihhihihi...Yes I have seen and I shoud  change all  the control points with one or two decimal digits. I have copy only the output generated with the tool.

Comment: @VincentFourmond I have understood now your comment. I'm agree the algorithm od the tool to produce the tikz output with several digits. :-( I'm sorry.

Answer (score 14):

For drawing people, have a look at [tikzpeople](https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzpeople/tikzpeople.pdf).

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
    
    \node[bob,minimum size=1cm] at (-2,0) {Transplant};
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
    \node[yshift=-0.7cm] at (2,1.5) {$HT(t): 0000....0 111111111$};
    \draw (2,-0.2) -- (2,0.2) node[yshift=-0.7cm] {$t_0$};
    \node[yshift=-0.5cm] at (1,0) {$t \longrightarrow$};
    

        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is a `pic` of a generic patient (it wears a hospital gown, clearly ;-P) for my slides.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/omino/.style={code={
        % Little human being R. Giannetti CC-BY-SA 4.0
        \draw[#1]
        (0.131198,0.557601) .. controls (0.186628,0.603975) and (0.219299,0.676919) ..
        (0.219299,0.754395) .. controls (0.219299,0.890048) and (0.121113,1) ..
        (-2.43666e-07,1) coordinate(-head).. controls (-0.121114,1) and (-0.219299,0.890048) ..
        (-0.219299,0.754395) .. controls (-0.219299,0.67227) and (-0.182632,0.595593) ..
        (-0.121639,0.550018) -- (-0.561425,-0.368407) --
        (-0.350879,-0.368407) coordinate[pos=0.5] (-left hand)  --
        (-0.280715,-0.228075) -- (-0.350879,-0.649122) --
        (-0.140332,-0.649122) -- (-0.140332,-1) --
        (0.140332,-1) coordinate[pos=0.5](-foot) -- (0.140332,-0.649122) --
        (0.350878,-0.649122) -- (0.280714,-0.228075) -- (0.350878,-0.368407) --
        (0.561425,-0.368407) coordinate[pos=0.5] (-right hand) --
        (0.140332,0.543897) -- cycle;
        \path (-head) -- coordinate[midway](-heart) (-foot);
    }},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw pic(P){omino={draw=red, fill=red!10}};
    \foreach \anc/\ang in {head/90, left hand/180, right hand/0, foot/-90, heart/45} {
        \draw (P-\anc) node[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt]{}
            -- ++(\ang:1) node[font=\tiny, fill=white]{\anc};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: I draw that in [xfig](https://www.xfig.org/), exported as Ti*k*Z and then I used a simple python script to normalize the coordinates and center the figure. If anyone is interested, please just tell me (a question could be ok).

Comment: Why is your person facing away from me?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I normally connect strange electronic equipment to them, so better not showing eyes... ;-P

Comment: I was referring not to the eyes, but the hands.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes oh --- well, my artistic skills are what they are ;-P --- for something I choose to study engineering. Hmmm... I don't see it (confirming artistic capabilities)

Comment: I am an engineer too (the art looks great!!).  I was referring to your sense of right/left.  The positioning of the "right" hand tells me the person is facing away from me, LOL.  I am just being a pain, sorry.  I guess I am just applying a "right hand rule".

Comment: That is to say, I am poking you for picking a "left handed" coordinate system.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes ahhhh that's because I am also completely non-lateralized. My wife tells me at least twice a week "your *other* left!!!"